# Unable to call javascript function on change in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display the text "Hello World" when "Pear" is selected in the dropdown.
Can someone help me with this ?
Thanks in advance!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
<select id="searchtime">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
</form>

<p id="text" hidden>Hello World>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select#searchtime").on("change", function(e) {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        if (valueSelected=="Pear"){
            $("#text").show();
         }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Fix your typo error** in console and it will work, **if you also include jquery in document**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to make it work properly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <select id="searchtime">
                <option>Apple</option>
                <option>Pear</option>
                <option>Banana</option>
                <option>Orange</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <p id="text" hidden>Hello World</p>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select#searchtime").on("change", function(e) {
                var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
                var valueSelected = this.value;
                if (valueSelected=="Pear"){
                    $("#text").show();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the things you missed in writing your code:

1. You didn't close the `p` tag you opened.
2. You didn't write a Closing Curly Bracket and a Closing Parenthesis for the `$(...).on("change", function(e){...});` part.
3. You didn't include jQuery in your code.

Hope I've helped you.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. The text is "Hello World" not getting displayed even with your code. Is it working for you ?

Comment: @Judil, Sorry, that was my mistake. I changed the code so it will work for you now.